# Switching between a "normal" view and a Split View Controller on orientation change IPad

Tags: ios, uiview

I have an iPad application I am writing; I would like to display a "normal" view when the device is in portrait orientation and a "Split View" when the device is changed to landscape mode.

I can get the device to switch "normal views", however I don't see an apparent way to do this in my view controller.

My ViewController has two UIViews, one called portrait and one called landscape. In Interface Builder I assign a UIView to each of these properties. Then, when the device orientation is changed, "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" is called and my views change. How can I assign "portrait" to that of a Split View Controller?

Am I way off base with this question?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following tutorial useful: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/04/05/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world/

The source code can be downloaded from http://staging.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/iPadHelloWorld1.zip